# What happens to Bitbucket forks if the original repository gets deleted or access rights get changed?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-fork

The title pretty much covers what I'm asking for.

What happens to a Bitbucket fork in following cases:

1. If the original repository gets deleted?
2. If the owner of the original repository revokes the read rights from the owner of the fork?
3. Also what happens to the history of the previous commits? If the repo stays intact, does also the history of commits stay intact?

Both repos (original and fork) are private, in case that plays any role.

Comment: Indeed, the question you mentioned partially answers the core part of my question, but not specifically points 2 and 3 (which I added now).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is only a partial answer. I still find it to be useful even after seeing the possible duplicate (since there are no references). Also, it can be used by others to draw further conclusions.

1. What happens to a fork when the original repository gets deleted?

   [It will remain:](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-or-fork-your-repository-221450630.html)

   > So, unlike a branch, a fork is independent from the original
   >   repository. If the original repository is deleted, the fork remains.
   >   If you fork a repository, you get that repository and all of its
   >   branches.
2. What happens if the owner of the original repository revokes the read rights from the owner of the fork?

   Not 100%, but this is what the documentation says about [*disabling forking*](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-forks-in-bitbucket-server-776639958.html), which at least might be related:

   > Note that disabling forking on the parent repo doesn't delete any
   >   existing forks, and doesn't prevent those existing forks from being
   >   forked. Pull requests will still work from the existing forks.
   >   Furthermore, commits in the parent are viewable via the fork if the
   >   SHA1 hash is known to the user.